# Knockout Can I get around this computed loop?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following structure for a bunch of objects in my viewmodel

I have an underlying array filled with objects that have ko.observable items in.

Ex:  selections = [{Legs:{'0':ko.observable(12)}}, {Legs:{'0':ko.observable(0)}}]

What I am trying to achieve is that when a user clicks on a checkbox, that should toggle the Selected value of that Runner. Now when that happens I would also like to update the Cache value to reflect the Runners selected state

**Cache is used as binary storage   12  ==   1100  == Checkboxes 3 and 4 are checked**

Now all of that I can get to work no problem, I obviously don't need to even make Cache observable.

But, I also have a need to programatically change the Cache values, and I would like the checkboxes to reflect these changes automatically.

What is below sorta works, but creates a Loop, which knockout gracefully handles, but its results are unreliable and this slows things down.

**How can I create this binding setup?**

```
function Runner(name, odds, race, leg, post) {
    var runner = {
        Name: name,
        Odds: odds,
        Post: post,
        Race: race,
        Leg: leg,
        Cache: selections[race].Legs[leg],
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Enabled: ko.observable(true),
        Valid: true
    };

    runner.Check = ko.computed(function() {
        if (!this.Enabled.peek() || !this.Valid ) return;
        var checked = this.Selected();
        var cache = this.Cache();

        if (checked) {
            this.Cache(cache | 1 << this.Post);
        } else {
            this.Cache(cache & ~(1 << this.Post));
        }

    }, runner);

    return runner;
}
```

**Edit**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected, enable: Enabled"/>
```

Comment: I can't figure out how the Check computed is supposed to relate to a runner.  Can you show us your markup or create a fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: User clicks checkbox -> Selected changes to match -> Check fires since Selected changed -> Sets proper bit flag in Cache -> (loop start here) Calls Check since Cache changed etc... Oh I guess I could add a line that said: check the bit value and if it is the same as Selected already then do nothing, which would exit the loop yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a moment of clarity after writing my question. But I think its a good question none the less so rather than changing or removing my question ill just post my newest solution and get some critique hopefully.

So in the end I forgo the Selected value entirely

**Note** The this.Post + 1 is specific to my needs, its not needed normally, I simply wish to leave the first bit unused for future use.

```
    runner.Check = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var cache = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.Cache); //Edit 1
            return cache & 1 << (this.Post + 1);
        },
        write:function(value) {
            var cache = this.Cache();
            if (!this.Enabled.peek() || !this.Valid || this.Post === -1) return;
            var mask = 1 << (this.Post+1);
            if(value === !(cache & mask)){ //Edit 2
                this.Cache(value ? cache | mask : cache & ~mask);
            }
        }
    }, runner);
```

One bad thing about doing things this way is that if I have 20 runners who all use the same Cache, then when a user selects 1 of them all 20 will re-check themselves...

For my specific case a future change may be removing the Peek on Enabled, and performing a check that says if !Enabled then turn that bit off by default rather than possibly allowing a Disabled Checked checkbox.

**Edit**

Changed 'read' function to use unwrapObservable() in case the Cache is cleared by ways of the observable being deleted/removed elsewhere.

**Edit 2**

While answering a comment in the original question I realized that to help prevent some redundant calls I could add a check to see if the bit's value is already equal to value and if so do nothing, so if programatically I try to turn on a bit that is already on then it won't fire the computed since nothing has actually changed.